# get image width after jquery cycle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, jquery-cycle

I've been trying to implement javascript resize for jquery cycle but when I go to the next slide and resize the browser window I loose the width of the images and everything goes bananas. Not sure what to do next...

Here is the javascript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
function resizeImage() {
var slideImageHeight = $(window).height()-110,
    slideImageWidth = $('#slideshow img').width(),
    slideShowImageHeight = $(window).height()-123;

    $('.gallery_item').css('height', slideImageHeight);
    $('#slideshow img').attr('height', slideImageHeight);

    $('#slideshow').css('height', slideShowImageHeight);
    $('#slideshow img').attr('height', slideShowImageHeight);

    $('.pgwrap').css('width',slideImageWidth);
};
$(window).resize(function(){
     resizeImage();
}).trigger('resize');

$(window).load(function(){
     resizeImage();
});

$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    speed: 200, 
    prev:   '#prev', 
    next:   '#next', 
    timeout: 0 
});

});
```

You can also see it here running. http://stoorage.com/index2.html

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems here:

1) '#slideshow img' is not discrete, as there are multiple images in #slideshow.
2) the resize function itself is called on window load & resize, but not after cycling images.

Cursory investigation indicates that the plugin does support callbacks through its 'after' parameter, so try this:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
  fx:     'scrollHorz', 
  speed: 200, 
  prev:   '#prev', 
  next:   '#next', 
  timeout: 0,
  after: resizeImage 
});
```

I think you can mitigate problem 1) by extending the selector like so:

```
slideImageWidth = $('#slideshow img:visible').width()
```